# Dictionary<KeyValuePair<T, E>, V> simultaneous access to KeyValuePair

Tags: c#

I use the **KeyValuePair** type to store Rows / Columns data. And I need to implement the AddRow / AddColumn

```
public static Dictionary<KeyValuePair<T, E>, V> list = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<T, E>, V>();
public KeyValuePair<T, E> val;
public void AddRow(T row)
{
       val = new KeyValuePair<T, E>(row, default(E));
       list.Add(val, default(V));
}
public void AddColumn(E column)
{
       val = new KeyValuePair<T, E>(default(T), column);
       list.Add(val, default(V));
}
```

In my implementation, two KeyValuePair objects are created, and accordingly I can not assign values to Key / Value, because they are accessible, read-only. How best to solve my problem or make separate classes for storing Row / Column and then the common class for Table?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong data structure. Dictionaries provide fast access to values based on unique keys, not as a tabular data structure. Look into DataTable.

Comment: I agree with @matt.  This looks like the wrong data structure, and you're reinventing the wheel (in this case, the wheel is a `DataTable`).

Comment: @Matt, I have a task to implement the generic class table <T1, T2, T3> which is better to use the data structure to store row / column / value? I tend to the dictionary <keyvaluepair <T1, T2>, T3> or tuple ?